Making the icon always shown without hovering
I'm using Instagram feed library called Flocker.
There's a feature that leads user to original Instagram post when user hover cursor on the post and click on it.
But since there are no hovering action on mobile devices,
user has to tab on post once to make the button shows up
and user has to tab once more to open original Instagram post.
On desktop, if hovered, the button shows up so only one click leads to instagram.
I want to reduce twice tapping to once on mobile device
But seems hard to find a way..
I thought I have to add a class to make it always shown
but when observed with developer tool, there's no class added when hovered.
https://stunvers.com/
this is the website I put Instagram feed
and 'figure class="flockler-wall_v2-item__context post__context__instagram"'
is the button that should be always shown on mobile device
Can you guys help me with this??
Want to reduce tapping twice into once on mobile device

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why offsite links are not good

in your wordpress dashboard navigate to Appearance > Customize and click on Additional CSS , then just add this css's :
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .flockler-wall_v2-item__context {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}

this part of css make the button always visible on mobile devices
hope its help you

Thank you for this code You saved my life sir
